# HTML table column leaves blank space

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to make a table for pricing on my website; however, the left-hand side of the table leaves blank space in its columns.

```
<h1>Pricing</h1>
    <table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Service/Item</th><th>Price (GBP)</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td class="left"><h3>Full Diagnosis & Solution</h3></td><td>50.00</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="left"><h3>Low-End Glasses</h3></td><td>10</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="left"><h3>Mid-Range Glasses</h3></td><td>50</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="left"><h3>High-End Glasses</h3></td><td>65</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="left"><h3>Designer Glasses</h3></td><td>80</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried to make the columns stretch across two rows so that there would be no blank space but this did not solve the issue.

Image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSZAu.jpg

I would like the blank space to be removed so that the blank space is yellow.

Comment: Please post your css so we can see where is the problem.

Comment: set background color for `td` instead of setting background for `h3`

Answer (score 0):

Without the css, it looks like you gave background color to your letters instead of `<td>`. Here's a working snippet.

```css
table {
  width: 80%;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
}
thead th {
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: left;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #3b3b3b;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}
tbody td {
  background-color: #f0efe2;
  padding: 5px;
}
h3 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<h1>Pricing</h1>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Service/Item</th>
      <th>Price (GBP)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="left">
        <h3>Full Diagnosis & Solution</h3>
      </td>
      <td>50.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left">
        <h3>Low-End Glasses</h3>
      </td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left">
        <h3>Mid-Range Glasses</h3>
      </td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left">
        <h3>High-End Glasses</h3>
      </td>
      <td>65</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left">
        <h3>Designer Glasses</h3>
      </td>
      <td>80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Going through your screen shot , i can see that you might have added styles somewhere in your code to h3 ,

try giving width: 100% to your h3

or simply by writing this in your styles :

```
tbody tr td h3{
    widht :100% 
}
```

or remove this style from your h3 tag

```
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, however neither of these solutions worked.

Comment: can you paste the style of your left class ? 

as i am sure that it has been provided with 
display inline-block;

checkout this link and try removing the display inline-block property 

https://codepen.io/singhagam1/pen/zyWjLP

Comment: I have not got a left class - I only have style.css edit- thank you for your help I just had to remove the left class code as it was not neccessary